# Get current location from Google without sending users away for authentication

Tags: php, javascript, google-api

Is there any way to use Google's API to retrieve a user's current zipcode without explicitly asking them for permission? I understand Google now uses OAuth 2.0 which is an authentication protocol where a user must allow permission to a particular service. However, I would like to find a user's location without having to ask them!

Is this possible? I'm not interested in translating IP addresses as they typically return incorrect results. Likewise, HTML5's geolocation feature would not work as it too requires user permission.

Comment: Wanting to find a user's location without their permission, do you really think Google would allow that?

Comment: Try using the HTML5 geolocation feature available in many modern browsers: http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/

Comment: A remember once a few years ago seeing my city being listed as I was dabbling with their javascript API.

Comment: @potench - Thanks for the feedback, I've taken a look at the HTML5 feature but I fear it will turn too many of my clients away. Is there "any" other method that could achieve this? I'm asumming there is no way to change the allow/deny bar that the HTML5 feature puts up at the top.

Comment: @MarkAnderson yeah, you could triangulate based on IP using a back-end language (such as php) but it's not very precise.  Let users input their zipcode as a fallback for browsers that don't have geolocation capabilities - you will save a lot of development time =)

Comment: I'd say that, if a feature normally requires user permission, then overriding it (or wanting to) negates user wishes, and is in most cases unethical. Geolocation is the best you can do here. @AlexLunix - hopefully it is the user, not Google, who allows or disallows this choice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will definitely have to oAuth a user using Google (or Facebook ... or [insert social network here]) in order to gain access to any information (such as home or work "zipcode") about that user stored on a 3rd party site. But once authenticated, you wouldn't get a user's *current* zipcode or location.  Do you want their current location or their home address or their work address - you may want to clarify.  Anyways, if you want a user's current location I would suggest using the HTML5 geolocation API.

The simplest use of the geolocation API looks like this:

```
function get_location() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map);
}
```

That has no detection, no error handling, and no options. Your web application should probably include at least the first two of those. To detect support for the geolocation API, you can use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/):

```
function get_location() {
  if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map);
  } else {
    // no native support; maybe try Gears?
  }
}
```

Resources for HTML5 geolocation:

- http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html
- http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/
- W3 spec for HTML5 Geolocation API: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I guess I just have to assume that sites like Groupon and dabble.co are using geolocation lookup based on IP addresses huh :/

Comment: I just went to groupon.com to see, and it asked me to confirm that I'm in Chicago.. when I'm in Los Angeles.  So yeah maybe they are using IP triangulation which can be spotty...  They do have sign-in with Facebook options, which they can then request my home zip-code from for a better guess.  But it's still a guess - the HTML5 geolocation might be your surest bet.

Comment: Yea, geolocation is always going to be the best answer for getting what you want. But maybe my answer fits in as the `else`.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do similar things in a similar situation before. And the answer i came to is maybe not the prettiest thing, but it does work and you can get a zipcode.

There are a few services out there like it, but i've found that MaxMind is great at giving me a lat,lon that is pretty darn accurate (at least for city/zipcode readings). This gets rid of you having to deal with this yourself in php.

[maxmind link](http://www.maxmind.com/app/javascript_city)

Warning: you must either give a link back to maxmind, or buy a monthly license. Sorry, but you could dig around for other services - otherwise you gotta make one yourself.

So, the idea is that you include their script on your page - and now you have these functions on your page.

```
function geoip_country_code() { return 'US'; }
function geoip_country_name() { return 'United States'; }
function geoip_city()         { return 'San Diego'; }
function geoip_region()       { return 'CA'; }
function geoip_region_name()  { return 'California'; }
function geoip_latitude()     { return '32.7153'; }
function geoip_longitude()    { return '-117.1573'; }
function geoip_postal_code()  { return ''; }
function geoip_area_code()    { return '619'; }
function geoip_metro_code()   { return '825'; }
```

From here you need to do some geocoding (via [google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) or choose another). Get your response from the geocoding and you can loop through the results and pull out a zipcode. I could maybe dig up a bit more script if you need more input on that step.

Might not be the most elegant approach, but i too was constrained to not being able to use geolocation and was in a javascript only environment. This worked for me. Cheers.